# Quicker way to animate each word of a sentence?

Tags: jquery, css

I think I may need some help with CSS or Jquery, whichever one is more efficient with the least amount of code. Basically I want to change each word of a sentence to a different color one after the other. So lets say a sentence has 5 words. The first word turns red then back to black and then the second word turns red after the first word has reverted back to its original color and then on and on in an infinite loop going back to the first word. I cant figure it out so any help would be awesome. Thanks!

So far I have this:

```css
.element1 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
 animation-delay: 1s;
}
.element2 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
 animation-delay: 1s;
}
.element3 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
 animation-delay: 1s;
}
.element4 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
 animation-delay: 1s;
}
.element5 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
 animation-delay: 1s;
}
.element6 {
  animation: pulse 1s infinite;
 animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    color: black;
  }
  100% {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

and then the HTML I was thinking of wrapping each word into with a span tag.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). SO is **not a free coding or tutorial service**! You have to show that you've put some efford into solving your own problem.

Comment: What do you mean "quicker way" and "whichever one is faster"? If the animation is too fast the user will only see a blur. Please [edit] your question to describe the animation requirement in terms of milliseconds delay for each step in the animation, and to describe what you've already tried to implement it.

Comment: Im sorry, in my mind I thought there was a simple jquery animation answer to this post. What I was thinking was $('').animate('name') and some animation delay values and boom there was an answer. I was thinking short answer = short question. sorry again I will not do that anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though, the question is not very clear, but here is my attempt to give you initials, as per my understanding.

```js
var sentence = $('div#content').text();

var words = sentence.split(' ');

var spanWords = [];

$(words).each(function(i,word){ 
  if($.trim(word).length)
     {
       var span = $('<span>');
       span.text(word);
       spanWords.push(span)
       spanWords.push('&nbsp;')
     }
});

$('div#content').html(spanWords)

var start = function(element){
  if(element.next().length){
      setTimeout(function(){
      element.css({color: "#000"});
      start(element.next())
     },1000);
    }
  element.css({color: "#f00"});
}

start($('div#content span:eq(0)'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='content'>
  Hello world. you are beautiful.
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sorry for the  bad question.